# При компилировании через Pyinstaller ошибка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Сделал небольшую игру на Python 3.4 и надо её скомпилировать. в файле с игрой нажат Shift + ПКМ открыл окно команд, там ввел pyinstaller -w (название файлы).py Перехожу в папку dist нажимаю (название файлы).exe , а он выдает ошибку "Failed to execute script (название файла)".

**Вопрос**:
В чём может быть ошибка и как её исправить?

Comment: Можно увидеть название файла?

Comment: @Alban - TestGame.py , но как мне кажется ошибка никак с этим не связана,  файл компилируется, но .exe файл не работает.

Comment: Вы меняли имя ехе файла?

Comment: @Alban - нет, не менял